# Alternative for aliases to be seen inside shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, alias

I have set inside `.bashrc` some aliases that I need to be seen inside a shell script **I can't modify**.

So, as long as I can't expand the aliases inside that script, what alternative do I have?

*(For example, I need to define `python2.6` to be the same as `python`)*

Comment: Why not put those commands in scripts, and modify `PATH` to ensure they appear first?

Comment: @phs: I guess I was just hoping there is an easier way to do it... Thanks

Comment: Does your alias-based solution work? If not, why?

Comment: Oh, I see you've already posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can wrap the script, you can define aliases in the wrapper and source (`. /path/to/script`) the script. Both functions and aliases should work that way.

If you can't, you have to put the commands in PATH. Either as symlinks or as scripts.

Answer (score 6):

Define and export functions instead of using aliases.

Let's say your script uses `mv` without `-i` or `-v` and you want to add them, but can't modify the script.

```
function mv () { command mv -iv "$@"; }
export -f mv
```

Now your script will use those options. You can define the function from the command line or in a wrapper script.

The [Bash manual](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC85) says: "For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases."

Well written scripts use absolute paths to executables (e.g. `/bin/mv`). Doing so will prevent this technique from working and is good security practice.

Answer (score 1):

Bash functions are more versatile than aliases, and can serve the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shell option to expand aliases: `shopt -s expand_aliases`, however it is switched off for a reason - aliaises in shell scripts are a support nightmare.  The alternative is to use the full command, and recommended.